# mobile safari seems to unload html5 audio/video after navigation

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I create several popup-sites like this: (function createPopupManual)

```
success: function (data) {
            console.log("createPopupManual: Daten erhalten");
            var popupVar = "";
            var videoArray=[];

            if (data.length == 0) {
                popupVar = "<a href=\"#\" data-rel=\"back\" class=\"ui-btn\">Abbrechen</a>";
                $('#popupcardOuterDiv').html(popupVar);
            }

            $.each(data, function (i, field) {
                var displaynone = "";
                var pageToHide = field.step;
                var nextPage = parseInt(field.step)+1;
                var prevPage = parseInt(field.step)-1;

                var mediaContent = "";
                switch (field.medium) {
                    case "image":
                        mediaContent = "<div class=\"fullsize\" style=\"background-image: url(images/cardtodo/images/"+field.filename+");\"></div>";
                        break;

                    case "video":
                        mediaContent =  "<video class=\"\" id=\"video"+field.step+"\" controls preload='auto' width='320' height='240'>"+
                                            "<source src=\"images/cardtodo/movies/"+field.filename+"\" type=\"video/mp4\">"+
                                        "</video>";
                        break;

                    case "audio":
                        mediaContent =  "<audio class=\"\" id=\"audio"+field.step+"\" controls>"+
                                            "<source src=\"images/cardtodo/audio/"+field.filename+"\" type=\"audio/mp3\">"+
                                        "</audio>"+
                                        "<br /><button onclick=\"playPause('audio', "+field.step+")\">Play/Pause</button>";
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                if (field.step > 1) {
                    displaynone = "display: none;";
                }

                popupVar = popupVar + "<div id=\"popuppage"+field.step+"\" style=\"height: 100%; width: 100%;"+displaynone+"\">"+
                                        "<div class=\"popupTopLeft\">"+
                                            "<div style=\"position:relative;\">"+
                                                "<h1>Schritt"+ field.step +"</h1>"+
                                                "<p>"+ field.text +"</p>"+
                                            "</div>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class=\"popupTopRight\">"+
                                            mediaContent +
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class=\"popupBottomLeft\">"+
                                            "<a href=\"javascript:showPopupPage("+pageToHide+","+ prevPage +",1)\" class=\"ui-btn\">zur&uuml;ck</a>"+
                                            "<a href=\"#\" data-rel=\"back\" class=\"ui-btn\">Abbrechen</a>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div class=\"popupBottomRight\">"+
                                            "<a href=\"javascript:showPopupPage("+pageToHide+","+ nextPage +",2)\" class=\"ui-btn\">weiter</a>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                    "</div>";    
            });
            $('#popupcardOuterDiv').html(popupVar);
            callback();
        }
    });
```

data comes from a PHP/MySql Server.
As you see, there is a `mediaContent` where i want to bind in audio or video.
that all works. but for any reason, on mobile safari, it seems, that the audio content gets unload. if an navigation occurs, after playing audio/video file.
For example: I start the app on mobile safari and open the first popuppage
`<a href="#" data-position-to="window" class="ui-btn manualStartButton" data-card-id="1">Anleitung starten</a>`

```
$('.manualStartButton').on("click", function(){
                var $popup = $('#cardpopup');
                $popup.data("manualToLoad", $(this).data('card-id'));
                $popup.popup('open');
            });
```

```
$('#cardpopup').on({
                    popupbeforeposition: function(){
                        var h = $(document).height()-50;
                        var w = $(document).width()-50;
                        $("#cardpopup").css({
                                        "height": h,
                                        "width": w
                        });

                        createPopupManual($(this).data("manualToLoad"), function(){...doSomeCSSVoodoo...}
```

after this, my navigation code is:

```
function showPopupPage(pageToHide, pageToShow, direction){
    if ($('#video'+pageToHide).length) {
        if ($('#video'+pageToHide).get(0).paused) {
            // Do nothing
        }else{
            $('#video'+pageToHide).get(0).pause();               
        }   
        //$('#video'+pageToHide).get(0).currentTime = 0;
    }

    if ($('#audio'+pageToHide).length) {
        if ($('#audio'+pageToHide).get(0).paused) {
            // Do nothing
        }else{
            $('#audio'+pageToHide).get(0).pause();
        }   
        $('#audio'+pageToHide).get(0).currentTime = 0;
    }

    $('#popuppage'+pageToHide).hide();
    if (direction == 1){
        $('#popuppage'+pageToShow).show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 500);
    }else{
        $('#popuppage'+pageToShow).show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);
    }
}
```

i navigate on page 3 (the first with audio) the first time, i touch on the play button... audio works. play pause... works. i navigate to page 2 and back to 3... i can touch what i want, no audio.
the "play/pause" button

```
function playPause(type, mediaId) {
if (type=="audio")
    mymedia = $('#audio'+mediaId).get(0);
else
    mymedia = $('#video'+mediaId).get(0);

if (mymedia.paused){
    mymedia.play();
}else{
    mymedia.pause();
}
```

}

works at audio, if i add the `mymedia.load();` method. but is there an other way? i don't want to load the audio several times. with the load method video playback is also impossible, because the fullscreenmode of the video kills my navigation at this time.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why, but if i use

```
<audio src="images/cardtodo/audio/myaudio1.mp3" controls></audio>
```

instead of

```
<audio controls>
<source src="images/cardtodo/audio/myaudio1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

all works fine.